# Designing a CSS menu bar, 0 margins, but yet there is a gap

Tags: html, css, menu

I have been working on this menu bar for a while, and I can't get rid of this ~5 pixel gap between my menu bar and the main body div.

I know it isn't a line break before the div (one of the similar problems I loooked up) because when I delete the menu bar, the div sits right at the top of the page.

I have also tried putting 0 margins in every single item related to my menu. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Here's the test page: www.PartyArtisans.com/blank.php
and here's my css style sheet: http://www.partyartisans.com/style.css
Here's my menu bar CSS.

```
#menu ul,
#menu li,
#menu span,
#menu a {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#menu:after,
#menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

body {
        background-color: #95BDFF;
}


#menu {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu ul {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 10%, #b87adfc 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 10%, #b87adfc 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 10%,#b87adfc 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    width:920px;
                        }
#menu ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCF0FF 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCF0FF 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%,#CCF0FF 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CCF0FF);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CCF0FF',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
#menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #00C5FC;
}
#menu ul li a {
    width:auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #00C5FC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul ul {
    width:auto;
    background: #E8F8FF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
#menu ul ul li {
    width:auto;
    float: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    width:350px;
    color: #00C5FC;
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #333399;
    color: #EEFFFF;
}
```

And here's the html, though I don't imagine that would have anything to do with it:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Information</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="DanielPeterse.php">About Dan The Balloon Man</a></li>
                <li><a href="Jobs.php">Looking for a job?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="BalloonTwisting.php">Balloon Twisting Entertainment</a></li>
                <li><a href="FacePainting.php">Face Painting</a></li>
                <li><a href="InteractiveMusic.php">Interactive Music with Miss Mary Kate</a></li>               
                <li><a href="HouseBand.php">Party Artisans Cover Band</a></li>
                <li><a href="Decor.php">Balloon Decor and Large Sculptures</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Reviews.php">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="Booking.php">Book us!</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I know it's a little bit of a mess, I copied it and tinkered with it for a while to learn CSS as I go.

---

Solved: I managed to figure it out after downloading Firebug.
I changed

```
line-height: 24px;
```

to

```
line-height: 10px;
```

and how it looks how I want it to look. *Shrug*

Comment: What do you mean main body div? Where is the code for that div?

Comment: yeah its probably the div that has the spacing/padding

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U48Bs/ If I am not mistaken, there is no gap? So that gap has the be come from something else. Do you have set `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`? EDIT: Even then inserting the CSS you linked into the fiddle I can't reproduce the gap. By the way, I a value is zero, you don't have to write "0px", "0" is enough :-)

Comment: It appears that the line-height of the horizontal menu items is creating the gap. I changed the CSS for #menu to `line-height:10px;` and the gap was gone. Not necessarily a final solution, but definitely a clue. [jFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fgmHb/).

Comment: The line height thing did the trick, I tried it on my own right before reading your message about it.
I have no idea why it worked but it did :S

Comment: Don't edit the title to add "{Solved}".  Instead, either answer the question yourself and select that as the proper answer or, better yet, select the answer from below that provides the proper answer (such as the one from @korun)

Answer (score 3):

Replace `line-height: 24px;` in the `#menu` div with `line-height: 0px;`

Comment: Yeah, this works. I don't really understand it, but I've been engaging in the copy tutorials then hack and slash method of learning web design, so that is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

edit your style.css (Info taken from the website, not the code posted here)

you have told the #MainBody to have a 5pix border all around

```
#MainBody { 
background-image: url("http://www.partyartisans.com/icons/pattern8-pattern-43aSunset.png");
border-bottom-color: white;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 5px;
border-left-color: white;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 5px;
border-right-color: white;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 5px;
border-top-color: white; // get rid of this line
border-top-style: solid; // and this
border-top-width: 5px; // and this one too
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 900px;
}
```

and the MainBody box should connect to the menu

Comment: You edited your question while I was checking your websites layout... and that was the only 5px gap I found ;) I was too late...again ;) Nevermind.